# In gradle, how can I generate library jar from wsdl instead of generating source code?

Tags: gradle, wsdl

I have some wsdl files. Currently I'm using `wsimport` command to generate related source code files and include them into my project then git. However I don't need my git repo to be busy with generated files. I need only to package all these generated files into one library jar and push it into git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't commit the generated files to git. I'd put them under $buildDir so they are deleted via "clean" task. Then you need to wire your task into the task graph and also add the source directory to the main SourceSet. Eg:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library' 
task generateJava {
   // configure task inputs/outputs to benefit from up-to-date skipping 
   inputs.dir 'path/to/wsdl'
   outputs.dir "$buildDir/generated/java"
   doLast {
      // Use wsimport to read wsdl and write java files to the output directory 
   } 
} 

// add generated directory to the main SourceSet 
sourceSets.main.java.srcDir "$buildDir/generated/java"

// wire the task into the task graph 
compileJava.dependsOn generateJava
```